How to define diferent partitions for swap, home and root during Ubuntu's 24.04 LTS installation
I have a dual-boot system alongside Windows 10 that is already installed and running. When I installed Ubuntu 24.04 for the first time after the upgrade was available, I could not create three different partitions: swap, /, and home, so I installed them all together in the space I'd reserved for Ubuntu. Now that I need to reinstall Ubuntu, I want to create the appropriate partitions for each. I intend to install Ubuntu on a 500 GB SSD. I have about 212 GB for Ubuntu installation.Can anyone guide me so that I succeed this time?

I would specifically allocate 70 gigas, ext4 system for /, 8 gigas or triple the RAM if you hibernate, swap system for swap and the rest, ext4 system for /home

If new drive, be sure to use gpt partitioning. And if UEFI system you need an ESP - efi system partition FAT32 500 to 600MB with esp, boot flags. Swap of 4GB is all you need if not hibernating and equal to RAM plus maybe 10% if hibernating. But hibernating not recommended as many have issue with it. I always prefer to partition with gparted in advance & use manual or something else install option.

This question is similar to: Installing Ubuntu on a single partition. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I recommend you keep the default single partition for Ubuntu for new users. You don't need a swap partition (the default is a swap file) unless you have a laptop and want to enable hibernate (disabled by default). For a laptop, an encrypted single / is more important (in case you lose it, or someone steals it) than separate /home. You can manually set up encryption for /, /home, and swap partitions, but that is too much trouble now and later if you need to readjust the partition sizes. This is my opinion.

I would recommend having a separate $HOME and possibly a separate swap if you are going to enable hibernation. The current fashion(?) is to have a swap file for other uses of swap which can also be used for hibernation but there is even further problems getting this working.
A separate $HOME lets you upgrade easier as you can run your previous OS (say 22.04) along side your new one (say 24.04) with a common £HOME until you are satisfied everything is working correctly.
From (about 24.04) the Desktop installer has changed and does not let you create a new ESP (by hand) (UEFI) as a FAT32 but only as a vFAT partition which I do not know if it works. I got around this by a 22.04 install just to create it as FAT32 and then continued on to install 24.04. (Note: I changed from MBR to GPT at the same time.)
When installing, when you get to the question about Ubuntu install, Automatic or Do Something Else - then Do Something Else.
You can delete partitions to make space and then create the three partitions where you want to install them. one at / one at /home and one at /swap. I think you create the partition and then set the mount point. (I suspect you already have a ESP as you had a previous version of 24.04.)
Good luck
